# Gitflow: One feature per release?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

Does the `git-flow` workflow intend for one feature per release, so that as soon as a feature is merged into `develop`, a corresponding release branch is made? Or can a release branch contain multiple features (each of which were merged into `develop` that subsequently became a single release branch)?

I understand what's *possible* with git-flow. I'm asking what was the *intention* of git-flow regarding features and releases...what is the *best practice*, not all that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, GitFlow **permits you do so much features as you want.**

Now, it's your decision how you'll work with it.

Some developers develop one feature and when finish this feature creates a release.

Some developers develop many features and times in times (eg each two weeks) they creates a new release with all features that they have in the **develop** branch.

Comment: I understand that developers can do whatever they want and I'm not asking what's possible with git-flow. Many developers do horrible things and, for example, it's possible to riddle your code with `goto`'s. I'm asking what's *best*, what was the *intent* of the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Gitflow can contain multiple features per release as long as you are following the proper merging strategy, which it sounds like you are.